# Store quotes in parse

Tags: swift, parse-platform

So I am really new to parse and I have no idea how to store a famous quote and it's own author, so then I can use that information in my iOS app made with swift.

I have imported all the frameworks in order to make parse work but I don't know to to store that quotes with the authors and then retrieve the information to display the quote in a label and the author in another label. Please don't be rude, I don't get who to make this work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you want to save a text and retrieve to Parse

let's say you want to save some text into a class called Data

**Save**

```
var data = "Swift is nice"
var object = PFObject(className:"Data")
object["message"] = data
object.saveInBackground()
```

So I use the saveInBackground method just for simplicity however if you should other saveInBackground method where you could check if there is no error while you are saving into Parse.

**Retrieve**

@IBOutlet weak var textlabel:UILabel!

```
var query = PFQuery(className:"Data")
query.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects:PFObject?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
                        if error == nil { 
           let retrieveData = objects?.objectForKey("message") as! String
                             //so lets say you had a UILAbel 
                            self.textlabel.text = retrieveData
                        }
                   })
```

I used the getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock method because I assume that I have at least one object save in Parse. So if you are retrieve a lot of data you could findObjects method .
Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thanks, very useful! But what if I just want to add in the dashboard all the quotes with the author? Like: quote = "Stay Hungry, Stay Foolish". author = "Steve Jobs", and add all the quotes manually through the parse dashboard?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your comment on Lamars's fine answer:

Create a class ("Add class") "Quotes" in Parse, if you haven't already. Create a column in that class named "Quote", set it's type to String. Click "Add Row" and you will get a new row in your table. Double Click it's field and you can write your quote there.

This is me editing the usernameField in my Parse Class:
[image: This is me editing the usernameField in my Parse Class]

You could have another column named "Author" of type String, and just do the same thing, but if your app gets more advanced and you would like to display all the quotes from a specific author, you should add another class, named "Author". Add a column named "Name", double click and submit your name.

In your "Quotes" class, add a column named "Author", type Pointer, and make it point to your Author Class. Then copy the correct objectId from Pointer (let's sat Steve Jobs has objectId "12345678") and paste it to the "Author" column in Quotes. Now, if there's another quote by Steve Jobs, you can re-use that objectId, not having to store the name "Steve Jobs" more than once.

I understand you're new to Parse.com and maybe databases as well, but this way of creating relations is very good knowledge, if you want to design stuff in the future.

Parse has a great documentation, in Obj-C and Swift, check it out:
https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/guide